# what is wrong with this dup2 and pipes?

Tags: c++, pipe, parent-child, pid, dup2

What this code should do is: there are parent.cpp and child.cpp. Parent will send whatever is in the buffer to child and child will send back whatever received to parent. I do not know what I am doing wrong. I am confused what is missing in the parent and what else I should include into the child.

```
//parent.cpp
//Check for fork error
 if ( (pid = fork()) < 0 )
{
    cerr << "FORK ERROR" << endl;
    return -3;
}
else  if (pid == 0)  // Child 
{
    close(fd1[1]);//Close parent's stdout-write
    close(fd2[0]);//Close child's stdin-read
    if (fd1[0] != STDIN_FILENO)//Make sure file desc. matches
    {
        if (dup2(fd1[0], STDIN_FILENO) != STDIN_FILENO)
        {
            cerr << "dup2 error to stdin" << endl;
        }
        close(fd1[0]);
    }
    if (fd2[1] != STDOUT_FILENO)//Make sure file desc. mathces
    {
        if (dup2(fd2[1], STDOUT_FILENO) != STDOUT_FILENO)
        {
            cerr << "dup2 error to stdout" << endl;
        }
        close(fd2[1]);
    }
    if ( execl("./child", "child", (char *)0) < 0 )
    {
        cerr << "system error" << endl;
        return -4;
    }
    return 0;
}//end of child
else //parent
{
    int rv;
   close(fd1[0]);//Close parent's read
   close(fd2[1]);//close child's write
   if ( write(fd1[1], buffer, strlen(buffer)) != strlen(buffer))
    {
        cerr << "Write ERROR FROM PIPE" << endl;
    }
    if ( (rv = read(fd2[0], buffer, MAXLINE)) < 0 )
    {
        cerr << "READ ERROR FROM PIPE" << endl;
    }
    else if (rv == 0)
    {
        cerr << "Child Closed Pipe" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "Output of child is: " << buffer;
    return 0;
}//end of parent

//child.cpp
char line[1000];
int MAXLEN=1001;    
read(STDIN_FILENO, line, MAXLEN);
```

Comment: First, you should post complete code.  (A reader should be able to take what you've written and compile it without having to add a main function.)  Second, you should indicate what result you actually get.  Are you getting compiler errors, or run time errors?  If so, post them.  If there are no errors, what result are you getting?  How is it different from what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your processes are blocked.  You write a small amount of data to the child, which the child processes.  The child produces no output, however, but is waiting for more data.  The parent is now waiting for the child to give it some data, and the child is waiting for the parent, and you have a classic deadlock.  Try closing `fd1[1]` after the write in the parent, and before the `read`.  The child will realize there is no more data and will produce output prior to terminating.